# Правильная реализация удаления записи из базы данных с учетом времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, peewee

У меня есть база данных (PostgreSQL) с игроками, у каждого игрока в бд хранится время последней активности `last_activity` (utctimestamp)

Передо мной встала задача удалять игроков из бд, у которых время последней активности было 7 дней назад.

Каким образом можно это реализовать более логично? Я реализовал так, но не совсем уверен, что это правильно:

```
async def check_activity(app):
    while True:
        #Устанавливаем работу раз в час
        await sleep(3600)

        #Получаем всех игроков с базы данных
        players = await db.execute(BasePlayers.select().where(BasePlayers.activated != 0))

        #Получаем текущее время
        now = time.time()

        for u in players:
            #Если с последнего актива игрока прошло 7 дней удаляем профиль
            if now - u.last_activity > 604800:
                await db.execute(
                    BasePlayers.delete().where(BasePlayers.lobby_id == u.lobby_id,
                                               BasePlayers.user_id << [u.user_id, u.partner])
asyncio.ensure_future(check_activity(app))
```

Можно ли это реализовать допустим прямиком инструментами базы данных? Или улучшить это как-нибудь, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли это реализовать допустим прямиком инструментами базы данных?

```
delete from players where last_activity <= now() - '7day'::interval;
```